# how to add android drm plugin

Tags: android, exploit, drm

i'm trying to add kClearKey DRM plugin in my android phone(LG nexus 4). I tried following solution,but it doesn't work for me:

1)build the kClearPlugin from source code provided by google source code tree.
2)put libkClearPlugin.so shared library in /system/lib/drm/plugins/native
3)reboot phone
what i'm trying to do is run an exploit for android mediaserver(CVE-2015-6612). when i run the exploit, it throws an UnsupportedSchemeexception,which means kCkearPlugin is not installed on my android phone.

My specific question is: **How can i add this plugin to my android phone?**
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On an non-rooted Android device /system/lib is read only - i.e. you can't simply add a new DRM system in as you would like.

The Android documentation is still a little ambiguous on this as it says:

> For device manufacturers, content owners, and Internet digital media providers the DRM framework’s plugin architecture provides a means of adding support for a specific DRM scheme to the Android system.

This may give the impression that you anyone can add it but the DRMs are typically added by the device manufacturers.

In theory this stops someone coming along and overwriting the DRM with their own one to try to copy the content, but in practice DRM solutions will have protection against this anyway even if someone did this.